# Why is this javascript repeating?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm attempting to create an invoice system.I have the following code:

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("invoiceTable"),
    rIndex, cIndex;

  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
        rIndex = this.parentElement.rowIndex + 1;
        cIndex = this.cellindex + 1;
        document.getElementById("invoiceTable").insertRow(rIndex).innerHTML = `<tr>
          <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
          <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
          <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
          <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
          <td><div contenteditable></div></td>
          <td>
            <div>
              <button
                type="button"
                name="button"
                onclick="addRow()"
                style="background-color: Transparent; border: none; color: green;"
              >
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>`;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS/CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
        <table class="table thead-dark table-hover border-bottom" id="invoiceTable">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 10%">Item</th>
              <th style="width: 50%">Description</th>
              <th style="width: 5%">Qty</th>
              <th style="width: 10%">Price</th>
              <th style="width: 10%">Amount</th>
              <th style=>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div><button type="button" name="button" onclick="addRow()" style="background-color:Transparent; border:none; color:green;"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- /role main -->
```

Now this works OK, but the issue arises after I click the button to add a row. Once the button is clicked, simply clicking the row the button was in would add yet another row. Also, clicking in the header adds row after the button is clicked. I'm pretty sure I need to tell the script to stop doing things, but I'm a neophyte at best where JS is concerned, so I don't know how. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want the add row button to work only once? You've set up an onclick event handler for every cell in every row.

Comment: @Yishmeray Yes. I'd love that. Asi I said, I'm green when it comes to JS, so I probably did this inadvertently.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. What browser are you in, maybe?

Comment: @Daviti I saw that almost immediately after posting ans changed the title. Sorry to have wastes your time, and thank you for keeping an eye out.

Comment: @KinoBacaltos I only tested in Chrome so far. UPDATE: I tried it in other browsers (Edge, Firefox, Opera) I get the same results.

Comment: There are a few different ways to do this. 1) You may want to remove the button inside the code. 2)  Change the script to define what is in the table, not insert (add) new rows. 3) remove the event from the button.  
Is there any preference on your side?

Comment: @Phy I'd Love to keep the button in the table (makes for a good UX IMO as the user wouldnt have to switch between KB and mouse), but if it's impossible so be it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is the same, but the id `invoiceTable` may be removed if you wish.

JS:

```
function addRow() {
var tbody = document.querySelector("tbody")

tbody.innerHTML +=
    '<tr>' +
        '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
        '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
        '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
        '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
        '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
        '<td><div><button type="button" name="button" onclick="addRow()" style="background-color:Transparent; border:none; color:green;"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></div></td>'; +
    '</tr>';
}
```

Because I didn't see the point of looping each element I just directly extended the new row. The + Button will still create a row at the very end, but nothing else does. Is this desired?

Comment: this works well. I had a feeling I was overthinking this one. The main reason I was looping through was that I wanted to make it so clicking the add button added the row right below the row you just clicked the button on. This works too as the audience for this application will likely have no need to insert line items into their invoices. now I just need to make a delete button for each line item.

Comment: `var allRows = tbody.querySelectorAll("tbody");` and a for loop might come in handy for your delete action. good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

`table.rows.length` will select all `rows` including the row which has `th`. Instead select only `tbody` `trs`.

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.querySelector("tbody"),
    rIndex, cIndex;
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    //   console.log(table.rows[i].cells);
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
        rIndex = this.parentElement.rowIndex + 1;
        cIndex = this.cellindex + 1;
        document.getElementById("invoiceTable").insertRow(rIndex).innerHTML = '' +
          '<tr>' +
          '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
          '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
          '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
          '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
          '<td><div contenteditable></div></td>' +
          '<td><div><button type="button" name="button" onclick="addRow()" style="background-color:Transparent; border:none; color:green;"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></div></td>'; +
        '</tr>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main role="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-5">
        <table class="table thead-dark table-hover border-bottom" id="invoiceTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 10%">Item</th>
              <th style="width: 50%">Description</th>
              <th style="width: 5%">Qty</th>
              <th style="width: 10%">Price</th>
              <th style="width: 10%">Amount</th>
              <th style=>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div contenteditable></div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div><button type="button" name="button" onclick="addRow()" style="background-color:Transparent; border:none; color:green;"><i
                        class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></button></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- /role main -->
```

Comment: For someone describing themselves as "neophyte at best " a more eloquent answer might be nice for them.

Comment: He did try, and i appreciate it. I also learned something (bonus!). The answer solves half the issue. the clicking header doesnt fire the script anymore, but the row click does (after clicking the button).

Comment: Try this before the for loop: table.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(button => button.removeAttribute("onclick"));

Comment: Should remove the `onclick` for all buttons which are in the table. Because the new button is added later it shouldn't be affected.

Comment: If you need something which doesn't use newish JS please leave a comment :)

Comment: @Phy Unfortunately, your suggestion did not work. To further illustrate the issue (I'm fairly certain I bungled the explanation), have a look at the following video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K7jALlEDMo3qdH4KdCdHalmNX7pGYcqL/view